# Identify the originating IP address of jdbc connection passing through a load balancer?

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, load-balancing

For http connections, many load balancers will place the originating IP address in an http header such as `X-Forwarded-For`, so that your application can log that IP.

Does the equivalent function exist for jdbc or odbc connections? I want my database server to log the IP address that **originated the connection**, not the load balancer's IP.

I have done many searches for the answer, but coming up short, so any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that in JDBC, because JDBC is only the Java API for databases. It consists of a set of interfaces and some concrete classes, and a specification on the behavior they must or should exhibit.

You will need to check the documentation of your database, your database driver and this loadbalancer to see what is possible. But the likely answer is no, because (relational) databases usually aren't loadbalanced like this (I assume you mean a forwarding proxy instead).